# For Windows 10 update, what are the IP address for firewall?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, security, windows-update

I have strict network where windows 10 updates failing because of strict firewall settings in Cisco/Juniper.

What are the microsoft ip ranges for windows 10 updates?

Comment: NO - i need IP ranges the router do not allow DNS entry or wild card whitelisting.

Comment: The ip addresses change.  That is the point of using a DNS entry

Comment: I just need temporary IP's because my system will do one time updates and then it will lock all the updates options for future. Right now its locked and windows failing to let me boot.

Comment: If your system is failing to boot how do you plan to add the rules to the firewall?  If you describe your actual problem we might be able to solve it instead of going down the route of preventing Windows from updating by blocking the ip address.  Even Windows 10 Home should let you delay an update for a small window of time.

Comment: If you have DNS, just ping them and you will get a set of IP Adresses.

Answer (score 1):

There are no permanent ranges for the updates. Depending on where you live, you will most likely get cached servers like Akamai. The only solution is to get a high end Firewall that supports DNS whitelisting or use Windows built-in Firewall which can allow filtering based on processes in addition to IP Addresses.